# Windows 10: Is there any way to increase the width of the clock in a horizontal taskbar?

Tags: windows, windows-10, taskbar

I haven't changed anything (that I know of), but now my horizontal taskbar clock only shows a time. I want it to show a date.

[image]

I've been reading articles that tell you how to fix this problem by making the taskbar vertical, but I don't want a vertical taskbar. As you can see, there is plenty of space on the left-hand side of these icons.Is there any way to increase the width of the clock in a horizontal taskbar?

Doubling the height did not fix the problem:

[image]

Something else I want to mention is I am scaling the size of apps, but when I said it to 100%, the problem doesn't go away:

[image]

[image]

---

Update: I don't know what I did, but for some reason clicking on and off the calendar a few times turned it back to the way I originally had it:

[image]

Here are some steps that might be relevant. I kept on trying to take the advice of the answer down below and click on my date/time to change the settings, but discord notifications kept getting in my way. I switched to discord to turn to do not disturb mode, and then when I was about to try again, I noticed my clock had been set back to normal.

I'm going to leave this open because I think the problem might come back, and I don't have a consistent way to fix it yet.

Comment: Go to taskbar settings, turn off "use small taskbar buttons"  this will give you 2 lines, clock on top and date underneath.  Or, you can drag your taskbar larger by unlocking it, if it is, then pulling up the taskbar and it will give you a double-line

Comment: @essjae that setting was already off. Whether it's on or off, I still only see a time.

Comment: That display is the way Windows 10 works. If you wish to see the date, there are two ways.  (a) click on the time and you see the date display.  (b) unlock the taskbar, grab the top line, make it double width and the date and day shows up.

Comment: @John b does not work.  I'll show you with an update to my OP

Comment: What version of Windows 10?  Windows 10 2004 x 2 here and Windows 10 2004 next x 1 as well.

Comment: @John added that info

Comment: I am using 125% on 1920x1080 and it works correctly. Consider now doing a Windows 10 Repair Install.   Go to the Media Creation Link:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Windows 10 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade Button) and select Run.

This will launch the Repair and proceed normally

Comment: @John I just ran an `sfc /scannow` and my OS is fine.  Could this still find/fix something?

Comment: It might.  Also run dism.exe  /online  /cleanup-image  /restorehealth  and restart when both are done.

Comment: That's funny, I had the same issue pop up 2 days ago! I'm also seeing all these posts saying "unlock taskbar and drag the right edge to make it wider!" but it won't let me. I even turned off the Notification Center system icon but no change. As an interim alternative, I changed the Short Date format to "ddd MMM dd" (Additional Settings in regional formatting settings allows you to type your own format). Hiding the year makes it narrow enough to show at least the "Wed Oct 14" part. Not an answer to original question though :/

Answer (score 1):

Thank you. This is the right way to show customized date format.

Back to the original question, the full solution is:

1. **Show date**: Go to Windows Settings, Turn OFF the 'Use small taskbar buttons". This will show two lines for the clock area, which is time on top, and date at the bottom.
2. **Show customized date format**: the date will show **SHORT** format by default, so if we want to customize the date format, just modify the SHORT format at the *Regional Setting - Additional Settings*. I'm using the `ddd, MMM dd, yyyy` for short date format, which is showing: `Tue, July 25, 2023`, it's informative and compact.

Comment: Thanks for contributing an answer. I have some follow-up questions: is it important to follow both of these steps or does either one fix the issue? "Unfortunately," I'm not experiencing the problem at this moment, so I can't check if it resolves the issue. I did toggle step 1 and noticed it reduced the time to one line, so I'm excited to see if this fixes the problem in the future.

Comment: Hi, that's what I'm doing, I think it's necessary to do both, to make sure date showing, and in desired format.

Answer (score 0):

Please try if the following method was helpful:

Settings--Date & time--Change date and time formats--Short date select as M/d/yyyy or yy/MM/dd

Comment: Only helps if you don't need the weekday

Answer (score 0):

If you are open to a third party solution, you could try [T-Clock](https://github.com/White-Tiger/T-Clock). It's a highly customizable clock that replaces the default one.

Answer (score 0):

When the date gets hidden, my current solution is not to display the year.

1. Right-click on clock
2. Adjust date, time & regional setting
3. Change date, time, or number formats
4. Additional settings
5. Date tab
6. Set short date to show the day of week but not year, for example: `ddd MMM dd`

If needed, you can still see the year by hovering the mouse over the clock.